# Unable to load certain URL in IFrame.. eg: google.com

Tags: iframe

I cannot load some sites in iframe  .. is there any other things which i have missed . can you explain me, how can i load those url's in iframe?

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.co.in">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I have done just the below thing . but it is not working                                                      <iframe src="http://www.google.co.in"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

The site might be sending an `X-Frame-Options:` header to prevent embedding in a frame (a common way to prevent "clickjacking").

I know the Google login pages do that. The developer console in Chrome should tell you if this (or anything else) is the case.

Comment: So if they use x-frame-options :deny then we cannot load those site in iframe ah?

Comment: Exactly. That's what that header is for :)